# MySQL: i need to pull the same column name from multiple rows into single query based on same conditions

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I want to combine the following queries into a single query:

```
SELECT val FROM resource WHERE facet="all" and urlId="1234"
SELECT val FROM resource WHERE facet="your" and urlId="1234"
SELECT val FROM resource WHERE facet="base" and urlId="1234"
```

Oh -- there are multiple "facets" for each urlId.  But only one row per "facet".  This table was setup by somebody else.  We are migrating away.  Obviously it would be better to have a column for each "facet" and a single row, but it's too late for that.

I can do this with multiple queries, but would like to have a faster/better solution.

```
<pre>
mysql> describe resource;
+-------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type                                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| resId       | int(11) unsigned                    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| urlId       | int(11)                             | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| sectionId   | int(3)                              | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| mode        | enum('archive','live','edit','dev') | NO   |     | edit              |                             |
| facet       | varchar(50)                         | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| typeId      | int(1)                              | NO   |     | 1                 |                             |
| val         | mediumtext                          | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| itemOrder   | tinyint(2)                          | NO   |     | 1                 |                             |
| editorId    | varchar(30)                         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| created     | datetime                            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastUpdated | timestamp                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.05 sec)
</pre>
```

Remember:  in soviet russia, SQL queries you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my preferred method which will use your indexes:

```
SELECT resource.val FROM
  ( (SELECT "all" AS name) UNION (SELECT "your") UNION (SELECT "base") ) AS facets
  LEFT JOIN resource ON( resource.facet  = facets.name AND resource.urlId = "1234" )
```

Comment: i like this approach, can you make the result at 3 columns in a single row, though?

Comment: @John I just posted a three column answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT val
FROM resource
WHERE urlId = '1234'
AND facet IN ('all', 'your', 'base');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) comparison operator.

E.g:

```
SELECT `val` FROM `resource` WHERE `urlId` = "1234" AND `facet` IN("all", "your", "base");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT val
FROM resource 
WHERE (facet = "all" or facet = "your" or facet = "base")
AND urlId = "1234"
```

or

```
SELECT val
FROM resource 
WHERE facet in ("all", "your", "base")
AND urlId = "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT val
FROM resource
WHERE urlId = '1234'
AND facet IN (
  SELECT "all", "your", "base";
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Result in three columns:

```
SELECT (SELECT val FROM resource WHERE facet="all" and urlId="1234"),
       (SELECT val FROM resource WHERE facet="your" and urlId="1234"),
       (SELECT val FROM resource WHERE facet="base" and urlId="1234")
```

But I personally don't recommend this, it's not scalable. Go with my other answer.

Comment: ah -- yeah that might run pretty slow.  this is for a migration routine, so it's going to run at least 5000 times.  thanks, though.  i can split the rows up into php arrays.

Comment: @John actually it's not slow it's as fast as my other answer but think of future when you might have 100 facets see how odd this query and its results will look.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  i'm a front-end dev but here we go ;)  actually since this is a one-time migration the number of facets won't change.  thanks!